# What is the worst case analysis of this code fragment?

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, performance

```
sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < i*i; j++)
    sum++;
```

I'm not entirely sure of my answer; I think the inner loop runs i^2 operations and the outer loop runs N times so the final answer would be O(N^3)?

Comment: I'm guessing the first two lines should be in the Code Block too?

Comment: To the right when you were asking your question there was this handy **How to Format** box. Worth a read, as is [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of operations is `sum = 1 + 4 + 9 + ... + N^2`. This is because when `i = 0`, `j` will increment itself 0 times. When `i = 1`, `j` will increment itself once. When `i = 2`, `j` will increment itself `4` times, and so on.

This sum is equal to `N(N + 1)(2N + 1)/6`, so the algorithm is indeed `O(N^3)`. You can [prove](http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/ira/infinity/answers/sm_sq_cb.html) this formula by induction.

Answer (score 0):

That looks right to me (asymptotically).